# ford focus cmax

Tags: ford, focus

when i turn the ignition nothing no click ,dash lights are all working fine ,headlights ect,ok it first happened a fortnight ago then when the mechanic came out it started first turn been fine up until this afternoon i had been out in it this morning .got aa out no start no sounds he cleaned the battery points still nothing he just sayed i dont know whats wrong was going to tow me to garage but when i phoned they were shut and the other garage in town cant look till next week ,so any ideas would be more than welcome cheers,

Comment: Welcome to the site. A little more information about the car would be helpful. What year is it? How old is the battery? Have you ensured it is in Park or neutral?

Comment: No offense, how much gasoline is in the car approximately?

Comment: @NumairAidroos - If the car doesn't even turn over (no crank; no start), what does it matter at this point if there's gas in the vehicle?

Comment: Weak distributor, dead starter, and a good battery. I just had to know how the fuel pump might be. Most times tapping the starter would kick it in action. I'd like to know how rusty the starter motor is. Anyway its been 4 hours. I doubt he'd answer.

Comment: sorry i took so long to get back to you but i had to go to hospital ,but a friend of mine put on an other starter motor now all good thanks for your help and your time cheers